# Need keywords to be recognized as such only in the correct places

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am new to Antlr and parsing, so this is a learning exercise for me.

I am trying to parse a language that allows free-format text in some locations.  The free-format text may therefore be ANY word or words, including the keywords in the language - their location in the language's sentences defines them as keywords or free text.

In the following example, the first instance of "JOB" is a keyword; the second "JOB" is free-form text:

```
JOB=(JOB)
```

I have tried the following grammar, which avoids defining the language's keywords in lexer rules.

```
grammar Test;

test1   :   'JOB' EQ OPAREN (utext) CPAREN ;
utext   :    UNQUOTEDTEXT ;

COMMA           :   ',' ;
OPAREN          :   '(' ;
CPAREN          :   ')' ;
EQ              :   '=' ;
UNQUOTEDTEXT    :   ~[a-z,()\'\" \r\n\t]*? ;
SPC             :   [ \t]+      -> skip  ;
```

I was hoping that by defining the keywords a string literals in the parser rules, as above, that they would apply only in the location in which they were defined.  This appears not to be the case.  On testing the "test1" rule (with the Antlr4 plug-in in IDEA), and using the above example phrase shown above - "JOB=(JOB)" (without quotes) - as input, I get the following error message:

```
line 1:5 mismatched input 'JOB' expecting UNQUOTEDTEXT
```

So after creating an implicit token for 'JOB', it looks like Antlr uses that token in other points in the parser grammar, too, i.e. whenever it sees the 'JOB' string.  To test this, I added another parser rule:

```
test2   :   'DATA' EQ OPAREN (utext) CPAREN ;
```

and tested with "DATA=(JOB)"

I got the following error (similar to before):

```
line 1:6 mismatched input 'JOB' expecting UNQUOTEDTEXT
```

Is there any way to ask Antlr to enforce the token recognition in the locations only where it is defined/introduced?

Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, never create lexer rules that potentially match zero chars (like your `UNQUOTEDTEXT` rule). This might cause the lexer to produce an infinite amount of empty-string tokens.

Comment: Will do.  Thank you - I appreciate your guidance.  I'm starting to read your blog on creating TL just now.  There's a lot to learn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is essentially a  Lake grammar, the opposite of an island grammar. A lake grammar is one in which you mostly have structured text and then lakes of stuff you don't care about. Generally the key is having some lexical Sentinel that says "enter unstructured text area" and then " reenter structured text area". In your case it seems to be (...). ANTLR has the notion of a lexical mode, which is what you want to to handle areas with different lexical structures. When you see a '(' you want to switch modes to some free-form area. When you see a ')' in that area you want to switch back to the default mode. Anyway ["mode"](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules#LexerRules-LexicalModes) is your key word here.

Comment: This kind of problem is surprisingly common in languages.  Lexical modes are a good idea, glead to hear Antlr has them.

Comment: Hi Ira. Yep, glad to have them back in v4 (lost in v2-v3).  I will add a comment for the question asker: if you do not have such an obvious lexical Sentinel, then you need to use a scannerless parser (i.e., one where the parser parses characters not tokens). Then, you can handle any sort of collocated stuff like C+SQL. ANTLR v4 can do that if you use my example where I literally convert characters to token objects. Some other parser generators, usually GLR ones, are scannerless by default.

Comment: We use GLR with lexical modes, but don't do scannerless.   Once in a while that is awkward, but we actually do pretty well in general.  We also have feedback from the parser about whether a keyword is expected or not; that means you can do keyword-in-context pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks for the extra insight in your follow-on note, Prof. Parr.  I will need to go this route as my language is more complex than my example suggests.  In that sense, my example was weak - I just wanted to make sure I got the point across without obscuring it with too much detail.  I will look up the C+SQL scannerless parser example in your V4 book.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with keywords that are sometimes only identifiers. I did it this way:

```
 OnlySometimesAKeyword : 'value' ;

 identifier 
     :   Identifier // defined as usual
     |   maybeKeywords
     ;

 maybeKeywords
     :   OnlySometimesAKeyword 
     // ...
     ;
```

In your parser rules simply use `identifier` instead of `Identifier` and you'll also be able to match the "maybe keywords". This will of course also match them in places where they will be keywords, but you could check this in the parser if necessary.